# Unable to delete rows from .csv file pyexcel

Tags: python, excel, csv, pyexcel

Here is my function:

```
     def prepare_file(time, mkt):
        # renames file to corresponding market name
        global previous_time
        for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'\Reports\*'):
            # if it's the most recently downloaded file
            if time > previous_time:
                previous_time = time
                # remove rows for properties that have not changed status
                sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name=file)
                for row in sheet:
                    if row[1] in changed_addresses:
                        pass
                    else:
                        del row
                # save file as correct name
                sheet.save_as(
                    os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\' + mkt[0] + '.csv'
                )
                os.remove(file)
```

The idea is to find the most recently downloaded file in a directory, open it, remove all rows that do not contain a address from the `changed_addresses` list, and save it as a string contained in the `mkt` list.

Everything works fine except for the deletion of the rows. It iterates through them correctly, and understands when a row should be deleted, but the outputted file still contains all the rows that should be gone.

is `del row` not the correct command for this case?

Comment: Is your file a csv file or an excel sheet?

Comment: It's a csv file.

Comment: `del row` just deletes the variable row in python, it won't delete the row in the file. The row remains unchanged. You can write the rows to a new csv file, and save this with a temp name, then rename it to the original. Do you specifically want to use `pyexcel` or will `csv` do?

Comment: `csv` would be fine if that makes things easier. I already imported pyexcel for other stuff so I was just continuing to use it. Would `csv` allow me to actually delete the rows without having to go through that process?

Comment: Could you provide a small sample of the file in question and the `changed_addresses` list?

Comment: Here is a dl link for one of the .csv files being edited (4kb): https://mega.nz/#!J2xXWITJ!3VFVpGTcNlVCJcdluzKKn_NG0cpkM-WXz_5JyY_QnLw

Comment: ['2317-2327 Intern…', '2317-2327 Intern…', '4140 Broadway'] corresponds to the Oakland file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `csv` I think this should work:

```
import csv
import os
import glob

def prepare_file(time, mkt):
   # renames file to corresponding market name
   global previous_time
   for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'\Reports\*'):
       # if it's the most recently downloaded file
       if time > previous_time:
           previous_time = time
           # remove rows for properties that have not changed status
           fin = open(file, 'r')
           fout = open((os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\' + mkt[0] + '.csv'), 'w', newline='')
           reader = csv.reader(fin)
           writer = csv.writer(fout)

           for row in reader:
               if row[1] not in changed_addresses:
                   writer.writerow(row)

           # close files
           fin.close()
           fout.close()

           # remove original
           os.remove(file)
```

So first opening your datafile with name `file`, and later saving it with the new name.

Comment: Same issue as before... The file still contains all the rows that should have been deleted.  I tested it to see if it does find matches between the list and the csv and it does. There is just something up with deleting the rows that is the issue.

Comment: @ZakSingh what does changed_adresses look like. I think the selection just fails. See my edit on the if statement. If the selection is not working properly, you should end up with an empty file now.

Comment: It isn't emptied. This is what an example changed_addresses looks like: ["1234 street", "2345 street"]

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem with your file and list, for me it's working perfectly with the data you supplied...

Comment: Well that's fascinating... Nothing else touches the files.

Comment: I copy and pasted your code in again and it works now. I must have screwed it up somehow initially. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

with [pyexcel](http://pyexcel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial05.html#remove-one-column-of-a-data-file), you need to use this syntax:

```
del sheet.row[index] or del sheet.row[index1, index2, index3]
```

Here is the example code:

```
 def prepare_file(time, mkt):
    # renames file to corresponding market name
    global previous_time
    for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'\Reports\*'):
        # if it's the most recently downloaded file
        if time > previous_time:
            previous_time = time
            # remove rows for properties that have not changed status
            sheet = pyexcel.get_sheet(file_name=file)
            indices_to_be_removed = [] # <-
            for index, row in enumerate(sheet):
                if row[1] in changed_addresses:
                    pass
                else:
                    indices_to_be_removed # <-
            # save file as correct name
            del sheet.row[indices_to_be_removed] # <-
            sheet.save_as(
                os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\' + mkt[0] + '.csv'
            )
            os.remove(file)
```

Alternatively, you can write up a filter and the advantage of the alternative is that it can deal with HUGE data file with custom memory footprint:

```
 def filter(file_name, changed_addresses):
     for row in pyexcel.iget_array(file_name=file_name):
         if row[1] in changed_addresses:
             yield row


 def prepare_file(time, mkt):
    # renames file to corresponding market name
    global previous_time
    for file in glob.glob(os.getcwd()+'\Reports\*'):
        # if it's the most recently downloaded file
        if time > previous_time:
            previous_time = time
            # remove rows for properties that have not changed status
            pyexcel.isave_as(array=filter(file, changed_addresses),
                             dest_file_name=os.getcwd() + '\\Reports\\' + mkt[0] + '.csv')
            os.remove(file)
```

But please remember to call at the end of your code. It will close all csv file handles.

```
 pyexcel.free_resources()
```